# Android INSTALL_REFERRER BroadcastReceiver not registering

Tags: android, xml, broadcastreceiver

For the last few days I have been attempting to get a simple INSTALL_REFERRER BroadcastReceiver test to work. But for whatever reason regardless of what I do I can't seem to get my broadcast receiver to register statically via the XML as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.packagepath" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.packagepath.CustomApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement-->;
    <receiver android:name=".CustomReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</manifest>
```

I'm 100% sure that the package names are correct. However, the only time my application will register a receiver is if I do it manually in my code like so:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (cr == null)
        cr = new CustomReceiver();
    IntentFilter ir = new IntentFilter("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER");
    registerReceiver(cr, ir);

    Intent i = new Intent("com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER");
    i.setPackage("com.packagepath");
    i.putExtra("referrer", "test");
    sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

For reference here is the CustomReceiver's code:

```
public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String D_TAG = "CustomBR";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(D_TAG, "CustomReceiver onReceive (context, intent)");
    }
}
```

I'm also having issues sending broadcast intents to the device via ADB. But once again for whatever reason I cannot get the broadcast to receive my application. I have tried numerous variations of the below examples with now luck. (note: the only thing that is changed is the packagepath)

```
am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.packagepath/.CustomReceiver

am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.packagepath/com.packagepath.CustomReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"

am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.packagepath/.CustomReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

The absolute only time I actually get the BroadcastReceiver to call is if I both manually register the receiver and manually invoke a broadcast within the application. Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong because I've been searching for days now and can't figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is an old question, and you probably figured it out by now, but:

1) In the manifest xml file, the receiver tag should (probably) be in `<application>`.
2) You don't need to create an intent filter for a "static" broadcast receiver. (ie: one defined in the manifest xml file)